# ELF generation using libelf hints

Tags: c, linux, elf, abi

I'm trying to generate a simple static ELF using libelf, but I seem to be having troubles.

I do not wish to generate an object file and then link it w/ LD, instead I wish to generate it on my own.

The main purpose of this program is to generate a static ELF with one LOAD segment and to execute the code.

The main problem is not in the shellcode itself,but probably in some of headers I try to produce in a wrong way. When  I try to run the generated ELF it gets killed as if the kernel doesn't manage to find the segment it just loaded, etc.

I would be fond if you guys could hint me.

create_elf.3.c

```
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libelf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned char code[] =
"\x0b\x58\x99\x52\x66\x68\x2d\x70"
"\x89\xe1\x52\x6a\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x61"
"\x73\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x52"
"\x51\x53\x89\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int           fd;
  Elf           *e;
  Elf_Scn       *scn;
  Elf_Data      *data;
  Elf32_Ehdr    *ehdr;
  Elf32_Phdr    *phdr;
  Elf32_Shdr    *shdr;
  if (argc != 2)
    errx(EX_USAGE,"input... ./%s filename\n",argv[0]);
  if (elf_version(EV_CURRENT) == EV_NONE)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf_version is ev_none, wtf? %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777)) < 0)
    errx(EX_OSERR, "open %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  if ((e = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_WRITE, NULL)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf_begin %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  if ((ehdr = elf32_newehdr(e)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newehdr %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  /*
     without these definitions objdump/readelf/strace/elf loader
     will fail to load the binary correctly
     be sure to pick them carefully and correctly, preferred exactly like the
     ones like the system you are running on (so if you are running x86,
     pick the same values you seen on a regular readelf -a /bin/ls
     */
  ehdr->e_ident[EI_DATA] = ELFDATA2LSB;
  ehdr->e_ident[EI_CLASS] = ELFCLASS32;
  ehdr->e_machine = EM_386;
  ehdr->e_type = ET_EXEC;
  ehdr->e_entry = 0x8040800;
  if ((phdr = elf32_newphdr(e,1)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newphdr %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  if ((scn = elf_newscn(e)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newscn %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  if ((data = elf_newdata(scn)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newdata %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  data->d_align = 4;
  data->d_off = 0LL;
  data->d_buf = code;
  data->d_type = ELF_T_WORD; // code :x
  data->d_size = sizeof(code);
  data->d_version = EV_CURRENT;
  if ((shdr = elf32_getshdr(scn)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_getshdr %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  shdr->sh_name = 0;
  shdr->sh_type = SHT_PROGBITS;
  shdr->sh_flags = SHF_EXECINSTR | SHF_ALLOC;
  shdr->sh_entsize = 0; // only used if we hold a table
  if (elf_update(e, ELF_C_NULL) < 0)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf_update_1 %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  phdr->p_type = PT_LOAD;
  phdr->p_offset = ehdr->e_phoff;
  phdr->p_filesz = elf32_fsize(ELF_T_PHDR, 1, EV_CURRENT);
  phdr->p_vaddr = 0x8040800;
  phdr->p_paddr = 0x8040800;
  phdr->p_align = 4;
  phdr->p_filesz = sizeof(code);
  phdr->p_memsz = sizeof(code);
  phdr->p_flags = PF_X | PF_R;
  elf_flagphdr(e, ELF_C_SET, ELF_F_DIRTY);
  if (elf_update(e, ELF_C_WRITE) < 0 )
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_update_2 %s\n",elf_errmsg(-1));
  elf_end(e);
  close(fd);
  return 1;
}
```

I would be fond if someone could hint me what's wrong here

Thanks

**edit**

Sorry for not giving more details,

The ELF generation seems to be working ok, I do not get any syntax errors etc,
however whenever I try to run ELF I generated, e.g ./create_elf.3 foo14 (and foo14 is the generated ELF)

It gets killed, as if execve/kernel doesn't wish to load it properly
I tried loading it w/ IDA but IDA shows the disassembled code fine enough

here's the output from readelf

```
readelf -a foo14
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8040800
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          116 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         2
  Section header string table index: 0
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0] <no-name>         NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] <no-name>         PROGBITS        00000000 000054 000020 00  AX  0   0  4
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
There are no section groups in this file.
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000034 0x08040800 0x08040800 0x00021 0x00021 R E 0x4
There is no dynamic section in this file.
There are no relocations in this file.
There are no unwind sections in this file.
No version information found in this file.
```

Comment: maybe you could tell us what's wrong?

Comment: What is the error? What is happening? What do you expect? What does `objdump` tells you about the ill-generated ELF file?  What does the `code` is supposed to do (most of us are not able to disassemble in their head)?

Comment: Why does your `main` ends with `return 1;`? It usually should be `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`

Comment: I added more details, the code is basically just some random shellcode I found on exploit-db. The main purpose of this program is to generate a static ELF with one LOAD segment and to execute the code. Whenever I execute it I get 'Killed' as if the kernel/execve fails to load it properly. I would be fond if anyone could hint me what's wrong with my steps here

Comment: Can you disassemble the resulting ELF binary, and at least verify that the code is supposed to be runnable ? (run objdump -D yourfile)

Comment: It is runnable :) it is not the main problem. The ELF fails to load properly, I do not seem to know why. I ran the shellcode in a separate.

Comment: Use a debugger like `gdb` and break at the first machine instruction.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch IF the ELF is invalid, the first machine instruction will never be reached.

Comment: @dotdot Please first reformat your code and output to remove all the extra empty lines, so we can actually see the code without (too much) scrolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it would be a good idea during testing to replace the code
fragment containing (naughty) shell code with something harmless, say:

```c
unsigned char code[] = {
    0xBB, 0x2A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* movl $42, %ebx */
    0xB8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* movl $1, %eax */
    0xCD, 0x80            /* int $0x80 */
};
```

On an i386 GNU/Linux system this revised code fragment causes the process
to immediately exit with an exit code of 42.

The following ASCII art illustrates the layout of the ELF executable
being built:

```
+----------------------------------+  <- LOADADDR (0x08048000)
|  The ELF Exec Header.            |  
+----------------------------------+
|  The ELF PHDR Table.             |
+----------------------------------+ <- ehdr->e_entry points here.
|  The ".text" section.            |
+----------------------------------+ <- The end of loadable region
|  The section name string table   |    for this object.
|  (optional).                     |
+----------------------------------+
|  Section headers:                |
|  - Header for section ".text".   |
|  - Section name string table     |
|    header.                       |
+----------------------------------+
```

The section name string table is optional.  It helps to neaten the
output of **readelf**.

```c
#define LOADADDR    0x08048000
```

The executable will be loaded at the virtual address named by
`LOADADDR`.  The value for `LOADADDR` is system dependent---a value of
0x08048000 seems to work well on my system.

The executable code fragment is placed just after the PHDR table.  The
`e_entry` field of the ELF Executable Header holds the virtual address
to which control will be transferred to.  The value of the field
should therefore be:

```c
size_t ehdrsz, phdrsz;

ehdrsz = elf32_fsize(ELF_T_EHDR, 1, EV_CURRENT);
phdrsz = elf32_fsize(ELF_T_PHDR, 1, EV_CURRENT);

/* ... */

ehdr->e_entry = LOADADDR + ehdrsz + phdrsz;
```

Code segments would use a data type of `ELF_T_BYTE` and a section type
of `SHT_PROGBITS`, with an alignment of 1.

```c
if ((scn = elf_newscn(e)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newscn %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));

if ((data = elf_newdata(scn)) == NULL)
    errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newdata %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));

data->d_align = 1;
data->d_off = 0LL;
data->d_buf = code;
data->d_type = ELF_T_BYTE;
data->d_size = sizeof(code);
data->d_version = EV_CURRENT;
```

The `sh_addr` field of the section header table entry holds the
virtual address of the start of the section's data.

```c
if ((shdr = elf32_getshdr(scn)) == NULL)
   errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_getshdr %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));

shdr->sh_name = 1;      /* Offset of ".text", see below. */
shdr->sh_type = SHT_PROGBITS;
shdr->sh_flags = SHF_EXECINSTR | SHF_ALLOC;
shdr->sh_addr = LOADADDR + ehdrsz + phdrsz;
```

The sole entry in the ELF Program Header table covers the area to be
loaded, starting with the ELF header and including the executable
code.

```c
if ((phdr = elf32_newphdr(e,1)) == NULL)
   errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newphdr %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));

phdr->p_type = PT_LOAD;
phdr->p_offset = 0;
phdr->p_filesz = ehdrsz + phdrsz + sizeof(code);
phdr->p_memsz = phdr->p_filesz;
phdr->p_vaddr = LOADADDR;
phdr->p_paddr = phdr->p_vaddr;
phdr->p_align = 4;
phdr->p_flags = PF_X | PF_R;
```

A section name string table is optional, and makes for nicer output
from **readelf**.  A hand-rolled string table suffices:

```c
unsigned char strtab[] = {
    0, '.', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', 0,
    '.', 's', 'h', 's', 't', 'r', 't', 'a', 'b', 0
};
```

The code to add the string table to the executable is:

```c
/*
 * Allocate a string table for section names.
 */
if ((scn = elf_newscn(e)) == NULL)
   errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newscn %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));

if ((data = elf_newdata(scn)) == NULL)
   errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_newdata %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));

data->d_align = 1;
data->d_off = 0LL;
data->d_buf = strtab;
data->d_type = ELF_T_BYTE;
data->d_size = sizeof(strtab);
data->d_version = EV_CURRENT;

if ((shdr = elf32_getshdr(scn)) == NULL)
   errx(EX_SOFTWARE,"elf32_getshdr %s\n", elf_errmsg(-1));   

shdr->sh_name = 7;      /* Offset of ".shstrtab". */
shdr->sh_type = SHT_STRTAB;
shdr->sh_flags = SHF_STRINGS;
```

With these changes the ELF binary created by your program should be
runnable.

```
% cc a.c -lelf
% ./a.out foo
% ./foo; echo $?
42
```

The structure of the generated executable would be as follows:

```
% readelf -a foo
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8048054
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          116 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         1
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         3
  Section header string table index: 2
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048054 000054 00000c 00  AX  0   0  1
  [ 2] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000060 000011 00   S  0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
There are no section groups in this file.
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x00060 0x00060 R E 0x4
 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
There is no dynamic section in this file.
There are no relocations in this file.
There are no unwind sections in this file.
No version information found in this file.
```

Comment: Minor nit: there is no `_exit` system call. It's `exit` or `exit(2)` if you want to underscore that it is the system call, and not libc function `exit(3)` that you are talking about. Also, you didn't explain why your `strtab` begins with 0.

Comment: The 'raw' system call appears to be spelled as `_exit()` by the POSIX standard.  ELF string tables usually start with a NUL byte so that an `sh_name` field of zero can be used to indicate a zero length string---please see the [libelf by Example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/files/Documentation/libelf-by-example) tutorial for more information.

Comment: The `_exit` in the POSIX standard is *not* a system call. It's a function: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exit.html The system call it will invoke on Linux is either `exit`, or `exit_group`.

Comment: Traditionally, the names of C library stubs are used to denote the  corresponding system calls; for example, see [this manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=_exit&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html#end).  That said, in recent GNU/Linux, the implementation of `_exit()` appears to invoke both `__NR_exit_group` *AND* `__NR_exit`, so the 1-1 correspondence no longer holds.   I guess I need to tweak my answer :).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for all the information, it did work :) I truly thank you (:

Comment: @jkoshy - Thank for your support w/ libelf. Could you please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065062/elftoolchain-how-to-build-the-libelf-library-w-o-the-rest-of-the-package

Answer (score 3):

The reason kernel refuses to run your program is quite simple:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000034 0x08040800 0x08040800 0x00021 0x00021 R E 0x4
```

This is invalid executable because the kernel can not mmap your `.text` with offset `0x34` at virtual address `0x08040800`. The file offset and the `VirtAddr` must have the same alignment.

Usually the first `LOAD` segment just includes the `ELF` header itself, i.e. has `Offset` of 0 (you would want to set size to `0x55` (`== 0x21 + 0x34`)). Alternatively, you can arrange for `Offset` to stay at `0x000034` and have a `VirtAddr` of `0x08040834`.