# ElfToolChain - How to build the libelf library w/o the rest of the package?

Tags: object, executable, loader, elf

I need to parse the loadable parts of an ELF executable for a simple loader. Found the nice "libelf by Example" tutorial (by J. Koshy) that gives a nice overview on the structure of an ELF. It then lead me to the [ELF Toolchain](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elftoolchain/) project, which implements, among other things, the `libelf` library of ELF handling functions.

The nice thing about using this library is that it encapsulates the variations in ELF formats and makes the code more portable and future proof. However, I found out that in order to be able to build the package on Ubuntu, I needed to install a great amount of prerequisites.

I tried to build only the libelf part by running `pmake` in the libelf directory, but got a build error complaining on missing header file - which is apparently automatically generated by the global make process and is architecture dependent.

My question is - how can I build just the `libelf` part of ELF Toolchain?

Answer (score 0):

You can build select parts of the Elftoolchain source tree by commenting out the appropriate `SUBDIR` lines in the top-level `Makefile`.

For building `libelf`, you should be able to get by with the following two directories:

```
% grep ^SUBDIR Makefile | head -2
SUBDIR += common
SUBDIR += libelf
```

**Note**: On Ubuntu, you could also use [GNU libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html), which offers a different implementation of the same API, and for which there appears to be [ready-made packages](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libelf).